# Копирование текста из виджета Label в буфер обмена

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

lbl = Label(root, text='hello world')
btn = Button(root, text='copy')

lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
btn.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Мне нужно дополнить программу функцией копирования. Видел копирование из виджета Scrolledtext, но с Label так не выходит. Как копировать текст из Label в буфер обмена?

Comment: а зачем ? вы ведь сами задаёте этот текст. переменная ='чётотам' и в Label(root, text=переменная.... ну и патом делаете с этой переменной что желаете.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно получить текст из виджета (в данном случае через `lbl['text']`, если нужно например из `Entry` - то с помощью метода `entry.get()`), потом добавить его в буфер обмена с помощью метода `root.clipboard_append`:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

lbl = Label(root, text='hello world')


def copy_to_clipboard():
    root.clipboard_clear()  # Очистить буфер обмена
    root.clipboard_append(lbl['text'])  # Добавить текст в буфер обмена


btn = Button(root, text='copy', command=copy_to_clipboard)

lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
btn.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Проблема: на IDE Thonny, когда я пытаюсь вставить скопированный текст в саму среду, она зависает вместе с окном `tkinter`, сам текст не копируется.. (Через какое то время развисает) Странно.

Comment: @Scourde, никогда не работал с Thonny. Возможно проблема в самой среде, у меня никаких проблем при вставке в любой редактор не возникает.